# Can't set a checkbox with selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm testing my app with tumblr and I have to log in and out as I go through procedures. While doing so, I'm having trouble clicking a checkbox that keeps popping up. How can I use selenium-webriver in python to click it?

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys
import smtplib

email = "xxx@hotmail.com"
pswd = "xxxxx"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actions = ActionChains(driver)


driver.get("https://www.tumblr.com/login")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_email").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_password").send_keys(pswd)
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_forms_submit").click()


#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)


time.sleep(5)


try:
    #checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor")
    #checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha")
    #checkbox.click()
    box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-token']")
    #box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#recaptcha-anchor")
    print(box.location, box.size)
    box.click()
    #actions.move_to_element(box)
    actions.click(box)
    #actions.perform()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

(EDIT)
My error reads:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tumblrtest.py", line 49, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 76, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/13/1rh6kf9x2k11pyfg6zsnfmg40000gn/T/tmpvkFkz_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10667)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/13/1rh6kf9x2k11pyfg6zsnfmg40000gn/T/tmpvkFkz_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10676)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/13/1rh6kf9x2k11pyfg6zsnfmg40000gn/T/tmpvkFkz_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/13/1rh6kf9x2k11pyfg6zsnfmg40000gn/T/tmpvkFkz_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12648)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/13/1rh6kf9x2k11pyfg6zsnfmg40000gn/T/tmpvkFkz_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12590)`

This was my error in Chrome: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tumblrtest.py", line 49, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 76, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

...nothing was clicked. :\

Comment: Which checkbox is the one that you are trying to click? It's not clear from your description. The `INPUT` that you are trying to click in your code (id=recaptcha-token) is hidden so Selenium won't interact with it by design.

Comment: @JeffC ...came to the conclusion that the `recaptcha-anchor` was the targeted value.

Answer (score 4):

Click the `recaptcha-anchor` instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor").click()
```

You might also need to [wait for the element to be clickable before performing an action](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

recaptcha_anchor = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))
)
recaptcha_anchor.click()
```

Comment: @marriedjane875 what happens exactly? Are you getting any errors? Can you share the complete code you have so far (and if possible include the link to the website)? Thanks!

Comment: I added all of my code above and added the error in the edit as well. Thanks a milli :)

Comment: still haven't foud a solution to the issue yet, but I won't give up :)

Answer (score 0):

Find recaptcha checbox with

```
recaptcha = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@role='presentation']"); time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))
```

then click it

```
recaptcha.click(); time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 1))
```

This method is currently working.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!